# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near'

Tags: mysql, sql-server

**error message**

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '() NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sent_by` varchar(30) NOT NULL' at line 4
```

**sql**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `chat` (

 `id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
 `member_id` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
 `time_sent` DATETIME( ) NOT NULL ,
 `content` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `sent_by` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
 `seen` INT( 1 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT =22 DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
```

what is the problem now? 
I just import into my server and happened this..
In my localhost is no problem when I import the sql

Comment: change line `\`time_sent\` DATETIME( ) NOT NULL ,` to `\`time_sent\` DATETIME NOT NULL ,`

Comment: @amdixon can you write that up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**syntax issue**

> - mysql doesnt know how to parse data_type of `datetime( )`.    it only understands datetime or datetime(0-6) as valid data_type s

**fix**

change

```
`time_sent` DATETIME( ) NOT NULL ,
```

to

```
`time_sent` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29833/1)

---

**[create table syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)**

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
    (create_definition,...)
    [table_options]
    [partition_options]

create_definition:
    col_name column_definition
    ...

column_definition:
    data_type [NOT NULL | NULL] [DEFAULT default_value]
    ...

data_type:
    ...
    | DATETIME[(fsp)]
    ...
```

[fsp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-type-overview.html) stands for fractional seconds part and must be between 0-6

from data_type syntax definition, mysql understands either

```
DATETIME(fsp)
```

or

```
DATETIME
```

but not

```
DATETIME()
```